# Assembly Load and loading the "sub-modules" dependencies - "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, dynamic, assemblies, module

There are several questions out there that ask the same question. However the answers they received I cannot understand. Similar questions:

- [Dynamically Load Assembly and manually force path to get referenced assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874277/dynamically-load-assembly-and-manually-force-path-to-get-referenced-assemblies) ;
- [Loading assemblies and its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012/loading-assemblies-and-its-dependencies-closed)

**The question in short:**

I need to figure out how dependencies, ie References in my *modules* can be loaded dynamically. Right now I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified" on Assemblies referenced in my so called *modules*.

I cannot really understand how to use the AssemblyResolve event.

**The longer version**

I have one application, MODULECONTROLLER, that loads separate modules.

These "separate modules" are located in well-known subdirectories, like

```
appBinDir\Modules\Module1
appBinDir\Modules\Module2
```

Each directory contains all the DLLs that exists in the bin-directory of those projects after a build.

So the MODULECONTROLLER loads all the DLLs contained in those folders using this code:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dllFileFullPath);
Assembly assembly = null;
assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
```

I am, as you can see, loading the byte[]-array (so I don't lock the DLL-files).

Now, in for example MODULE1, I have a static reference called MyGreatXmlProtocol. The MyGreatXmlProtocol.dll then also exists in the directory `appBinDir\Modules\Module1` and is loaded using the above code

When code in the MODULE1 tries to use this MyGreatXmlProtocol, I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyGreatXmlProtocol, Version=1.0.3797.26527, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So, in a post (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874277/dynamically-load-assembly-and-manually-force-path-to-get-referenced-assemblies)) they say that

> To my understanding reflection will
>   load the main assembly and then search
>   the GAC for the referenced assemblies,
>   if it cannot find it there, you can
>   then incorparate an assemblyResolve
>   event:

**First;** is it really needed to use the AssemblyResolve-event to make this work? Shouldn't my different MODULEs themself load their DLLs, as they are statically referenced?

**Second;** if AssemblyResolve is the way to go - how do I use it? I have attached a handler to the Event but I never get anything on MyGreatXmlProctol.

### Edit

Code regarding the AssemblyResolve-event handler:

```
public GUI()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    ...
}

// 
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.Name);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post code that shows how you subscribed to the AssemblyResolve event.

Answer (score 0):

try to do `assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);` to MyGreatXmlProtocol assembly. I read somewhere that if you load assembly by byte array you have to resolve dependencies manually.

Comment: yes, that is done. I tried to explain that in my post:
"The MyGreatXmlProtocol.dll then also exists in the directory appBinDir\Modules\Module1 and is loaded using the above code"

Comment: Yes, it does. I am sure that the MyGreatXmlProtocol.dll is loaded, I have breaked the app and "seen it happen". Also, this prints i den output: "'ModuleController.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'MyGreatXmlProtocol'"